# Aliasing a DOM function (Document.Write) and scripts on other domains

Tags: javascript, dom, document.write

I want to force external 3rd party scripts (on seperate domains) to use my own custom implementation of document.write when I load them on my domain.

ie:

```
document.write = function(args) {
    // My custom Function
    }
```

This works fine for scripts on the same domain, but scripts on other domains use the browser default. Can I override this?

Comment: where have you put document.write = function... in your html?

Comment: Its in an external script that is loaded (fully) before any of the other scripts. This script actually dynamically loads the other scripts, so it is guaranteed to run first.

Comment: I guess your code, if executed last should run your implementation, when calling document.write(...).

Comment: Are the other scripts writing to an iframe? Because that's the only way a different document.write could be getting called, because it's on a different document.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
(window.HTMLDocument ? HTMLDocument.prototype : document).write = function(s) {
    this.title = s;
}
```

Both in IE and in non-IE, "this" object is the browser document object.

Comment: That doesn't make a bit of difference :(

Comment: Thank you guys for minusing my help, however I am not going to withdraw my right answer. Anyway, I tested what I proposed and it indeed works. You can see it working: http://www.amplesdk.com/share/test.html